# Only one expression can be specified in Sql Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Only one expression can be specified in Sql Query

```
select PageID
    from page
    where PageID in (select DocumentId
                     from PDFDocument
                     where DocumentId in (select * from RunDocument)
                    )
```

[image]

Comment: Have you ever heard about `JOIN`? It will be much easier to express your query with `JOIN` instead of nested `IN` subquery.

Comment: i need this with sub query not with join SIR ,

Answer (score 3):

You have `select *` where only one column is expected.  You can fix this just by mentioning the column:

```
select PageID
from page
where PageID in (select DocumentId
                 from PDFDocument
                 where DocumentId in (select DocumentId from RunDocument)
---------------------------------------------^
                );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this.

```
SELECT pg.PageID
FROM   page pg
       INNER JOIN PDFDocument pd
               ON pd.DocumentId = pg.PageID
       INNER JOIN RunDocument rd
               ON rd.DocumentId = pd.DocumentId
```

Using Subquery

```
SELECT pg.PageID
FROM   page pg
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM   PDFDocument pd
                      INNER JOIN RunDocument rd
                              ON rd.DocumentId = pd.DocumentId
                                 AND pd.DocumentId = pg.PageID);
```